# Which of these ETFs would reduce my diversifiable risk?

Tags: investing, diversification

`ETF1` and `ETF2`, within the same sector, have a high Sortino ratio together.

Swapping `ETF2` with `ETF3`, a well-performing ETF that has diverse holdings (rather than holding stocks within the same industry sector as `ETF1`),  *reduces* the [Sortino ratio](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sortinoratio.asp) considerably. The same applies to the [Sharpe ratio](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sharperatio.asp) too.

Which one would reduce diversifiable risk with ETF1? `ETF2` within the same sector but a higher Sortino ratio or `ETF3` with diversified holdings and a lower Sortino ratio?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but the Sharpe ratio and Sortino ratio are measures of return _relative_ to their levels of risk. So it's entirely possible that ETF2 has lower risk (standard deviation of returns) _and_ a lower sharpe/sortino ratio.

Comment: @DStanley You're not misunderstanding the question. I'm a newbie at investing. Should I delete this question, as the premise is invalid?

Comment: Possibly, or make it more generic  - e.g. "how can I tell which ETF reduces my diversifiable risk?"

Comment: And I don't know how much of a newbie you are, but you might be trying to run when you should still be walking...

Comment: What do you recommend, @quid?

Comment: It's more important to be *really* comfortable with concepts before you start trying to apply really specific measurements.  The sharpe ratio is not a newbie thing.  Diversifying your portfolio is a complex idea these ratios are just a single tool to assist your efforts, they are is not the only tool.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to reduce diversifiable risk is to, well, diversify. So intuitively, ETF3 would reduce that risk since it's more diversified than ETF2, which has holdings in the same sector. The way to measure that is to look at the correlation of returns between the pairs of funds (there are online tools that will do this for you).

Note that the ratios you describe do not necessarily identify lower risk portfolios. Those ratios measure *returns* relative to their risk, so a portfolio with less risk might also have a lower sharpe/sortino ratio if it also has lower returns as a result.

What lower ratios *do* mean is that you're getting *less return* for your level of risk. So it sounds like ETF3 *probably* gives you less diversifiable risk, but at the expense of lower expected returns.